# Limit one user per IP in Drupal 6.22

Tags: drupal, module, ip

Recently I found that multiple accounts are being created in my Drupal 6.22 website by someone from a particular IP. Is someone aware of any modules to limit the user to create only one account per ip?
Thanks.

Comment: You might get better responses for this at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @shanethehat wow.. I didn't knew that.. Thanks for the tip..

Comment: You are aware that ip addresses are not necessarily unique to a single computer, that they change a lot for most internet users, and that many users can share the same ip, if they come from a network using NAT (like e.g. corporate networks)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use rules module for this. there is no direct module. Visit this link [click here](http://drupal.org/project/rules)